# No me muestra el mensaje al presionar el button

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

Hola buenas quería comentar que tengo el siguiente problema. Lo que sucede es que tengo un formulario al cual le deseo realizar algunas validaciones en php, la cosa es que al momento de presionar el button (el cual se encuentra dentro del formulario) deseo mostrar un mensaje para verificar que todo funciona correctamente, pero no me muestra el mensaje que deseo en el formulario.

Mi formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mensaje el cual deseo mostrar (validacion.php):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de enviar de presionar el el botón, debería aparecer ese mensaje aquí, pero no sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si logre redactar bien mi problema, pero **en resumen** lo que necesito es que al presionar el botón de agendar me muestra el mensaje que se encuentra en el archivo validacion.php

Comment: Sería mejor que en vede imágenes subas el *código*, así te podrán contestar mejor y será bien recibida tu respuesta, te aconsejo que hagas un recorrido del sitio de como preguntar.

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_: no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar validar desde recibir_reunion.php ya que es la accion que tu formulario realiza.

```
<?php
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if($titulo != ''){
      //Lo que tu codigo haria
   }else{
      echo "<h2>El campo es requerido.</h2>";
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

apenas vi tu mensaje en el grupo jeje, bueno mira no soy un experto en php y tal vez alguien mas podria corregirme pero noto varias cosas.

Tu validacion no se muestra por que (si no mal recuerdo) php es secuencial y que pasa que cuando haces el submit se recarga el archivo desde el principio(por que en tu caso supongo que el archivo que tienes en el action es el mismo formulario), por lo cual, no llega a ejecutar la validacion.

No es necesario que le pongas name y despues cheques si hay un post con el submit, simplemente con que revises si llegaron los datos del formulario por ejemplo:

```
$titulo = (isset($POST['titulo'])) ? POST['titulo'] : '' ;
```

Asi te ahorras un poco de lineas :D y ahora pues ya podrias hacer tus validaciones, yo te recomendaria que las pusieras en una funcion y asi por ejemplo podrias verificar todos los datos:

```
    function ValidaDatos()
{
    $aMensajes = [];
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $sVariableEvaluada = trim($_POST["$key"]);
        
        if (empty($sVariableEvaluada)) {
            $aMensajes[] = "Es requerido.";
        }
    }
}
```

Que pasa ahi, como $POST es un array con los datos enviados puedes utilizar un foreach para recorrerlo y asi hacer con los datos lo que quieras, por ejemplo yo eliminaba los espacios vacios(con trim) y despues checaba si estaba vacio (empty) y si lo estaba metia en un array el mensaje y ese array lo retornaba.

```
$mensajes = validaDatos();
```

y pues ya asi podrias mostrar los mensaje de error guardandolo en otra variable los mensajes retornados de la funcion.

Espero que te haya ayudado un poco, por lo general si solo quisieras mostrar esos mensajes deberias utilizar JS.

PD. no uses onclick en las etiquetas html hahaha, saludos.